# Setting a range variable using another range variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a bit of trouble with this and I'm not sure why...

My code (such that it is, a work in progress) is getting stuck on this line:

```
Set starRange = .Range(Cells(title), Cells(LR, 3))
```

Can I not use a range variable to set a new range in this way?

```
Sub cellPainter()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim starRange, titleRange, found As Range
Dim errorList() As String
Dim i, LR As Integer

i = 0
ReDim errorList(i)
errorList(i) = ""
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set titleRange = .Range("C4")
        If InStr(1, titleRange, "Title", vbBinaryCompare) < 1 Then
            Set found = .Range("C:C").Find("Title", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not found Is Nothing Then
                titleRange = found
            Else
                errorList(i) = ws.Name
                i = i + 1
                ReDim Preserve errorList(i)
            End If
        End If
        Set starRange = .Range(Cells(titleRange), Cells(LR, 3))
        For Each cell In starRange
            If InStr(1, cell, "*", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 40
            If InStr(1, cell, "*", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Range(cell, cell.Offset(0, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Next cell
    End With
Next ws

If errorList(0) <> "" Then
    txt = MsgBox("The following worksheets were missing the Title row, and no colour changes could be made:" & vbNewLine)
    For j = 0 To i
        txt = txt & vbCrLf & errorList(j)
    Next j
    MsgBox txt
End If

End Sub
```

Edit:
Rory cracked it!
When using a variable inside Range, the Cells property is not required:

```
Set starRange = .Range(titleRange, .Cells(LR, 3))
```

Comment: You need to qualify `Cells` too and titleRange is already a range:  `Set starRange = .Range(titleRange, .Cells(LR, 3))`. Note two dots, not one.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to search for the answer!
Thank you for cracking it :D

Comment: although uhh... it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you note the edit to my comment?

Comment: I did not - that was it!
cheers dude

Comment: Please note that `Dim starRange, titleRange, found As Range` will only define `found As Range` but the other 2 as `Variant` you need to specify a type for **every** variable like `Dim starRange As Range, titleRange As Range, found As Range` otherwise VBA automatically assumes `Variant`!

Comment: Is that so? Damn I thought if you listed them like that everything comma separated would be defined.
Cheers man!

Comment: "if you declare more than one variable with one As clause, you cannot supply an initializer for that group of variables." you're only right aint ya! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement